# Azure key vault certificate import cannot handle BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY

Tags: azure, certificate, rsa, azure-keyvault, private-key

I am trying to import a certificate.pem file to an azure key vault in the certificate section, that looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
{my key}
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
{my certificate}
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

However I get the error message:

> The specified PEM X.509 certificate content is in an unexpected
> format. Please check if certificate is in valid PEM format.

When I upload the certificate as this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
{my key}
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
{my certificate}
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I am getting the error:

> The type of the private key of the X.509 certificate content is not
> supported. Supported key types are: [ec, ec-hsm, rsa, rsa-hsm].

Can you tell me why I am not able to upload the certificate?

Under https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-key-matcher.html I checked the key and the certificate and everything seems fine there when I type in the key with "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that azure-key vault does not want you to upload private keys in RSA format:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
     {my key}
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

You can use openssl to convert it to PKCS8 private key:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in certificate.pem
```

This command will you give you a private key in PKCS8 format:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
     {my key}
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```